# How can I handle the state of a props in the correct method here? It doesn't update

Tags: reactjs

Why the "Initial Result" and the "Final Result" are the same in the console despite the fact that the state.result in the html is different and correct? Am I making it wrong?
I would like to have a text input that update the result when you type. Also when you deleted a letter with backspace, it's doesn't update.

I printed the values in the console but it's as the values are the past ones, not the current ones.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TQValueCalculator extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({result:0});
    this.input = React.createRef();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

calculateTQValue(letter) {
      switch(letter) {
        case 'a':
            return 1;
        case 'b':
            return 2;
        case 'c':
            return 3;
        default:
            return null;
      }
  }

handleChange(event) {

    this.setState({result: 0})

    console.log("Initial Result " + this.state.result);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.input.current.value.length; i++) {
        this.setState({result: this.state.result + 
        this.calculateTQValue(this.input.current.value.charAt(i))})
    }

    console.log("Final Result " + this.state.result);
}

render(){

    return(
      <div>

      <input
        type="text"
        name="word"
        placeholder='Write here...'
        defaultValue = ''
        ref={this.input}
        onInput={this.handleChange}
        >
      </input>

      <p>
        Result: {this.state.result}
      </p>

      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you should calculate the value and then update the state only once. Also when you want to use previous value of state you should use `this.setState(prevState=>({result: prevState.result + ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because setState in async.
The final result console log happens before the state is actually set.

(Also when the actual change happens the component re-renders which is why you see the correct values in the html but the console log has already happened.)

From docs

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

You can pass a callback to check the value after the change occurs

```
this.setState({ key: value }, function () {
    console.log(this.state.key)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use setState(), you invoke async function and an async function does not response immediately. It takes time. If you need to check state after setstate(), you should use

```
this.setState({result: this.state.result,()=>console.log(this.state.result))
```

Also, when state updates, your component and it’s children re-render. Because of this you can read updated state in your render function.